# Calendar I created on "com.google" on android erased after sync

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I created a new calendar on android and added events.

After first sync or after a few seconds it's erasing. Can somebody help with this problem?

**Code:**

```
private void createCalendar(Context context, String accName) {
    Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    final ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accName);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, CALENDAR_NAME);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, CALENDAR_NAME);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xEA8561);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, accName);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    v.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);

    calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accName)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google")
            .build();

    calUri = calUri.buildUpon().build();

    final Uri result = context.getContentResolver().insert(calUri, v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortinately this is a known issue with the calendar API. you have only one option if you want to use the Android calendar- create the calendar as a local one and synchronize it yourself.